# MOSFET voltage drop and LED flickering

Tags: transistors, pwm, nodemcu

I've build a LED strip controller using NodeMCU and a transistor STP16NF06FP according to the schematic below:
[image]

LEDs were powered with 24 V power supply and I want to regulate it by changing the voltage using PWM on mcu. So for the simplicity's sake I output 255 on PWM pin D5 and the voltage output is ~16 V instead of ~24V also LEDs are flickering.

When I power NodeMCU from USB instead of voltage stabiliser then it is not flickering, but the voltages remain the same.

How to get rid of flickering and get a higher voltages?  Max power output from power supply is 0.5 A and it is enought to power LEDs.

When I mount IFRZ44N instead of STP I get ~16 V but the LEDs barely light.
With TIP120 there is no flickering but the output is ~16.7 V (so still a voltage drop, I wanted to replace to MOSTFET as these should have less voltage drop than NPN).

Here is the code for NodeMCU https://bitbucket.org/mdczaplicki/smarthome/src/master/node_mcu/node_mcu.ino

Comment: Is the LED strip rated for 24 VDC operation ?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The STP16NF06FP requires 10V Vgs to drive it reliably fully on. You are giving it 3.3V approximately.

You either need to find a logic-level MOSFET that is rated for 3.3V or lower Vgs or make a gate driver circuit to give more voltage to the gate.

Comment: According to my datasheet Vgs is 20 V, but I see now. Is it smart to use second transistor to control this one or is it an overkill and I should buy for example: PSMN2R7-30PL?

Comment: If your PWM frequency is slow you could use a jellybean NPN BJT with a base resistor and pullup to +12. Eg. 1K  for each resistor. 1/4W for the pullup. PWM logic is reversed (high = off).

Comment: I've got no 12 V in my circuit, though isn't TIP120 an NPN BJT? I think I will go with logic level mosfets, maybe I will buy more of them just to have them. Is there any you could recommend for my specification?

Comment: You could add a 78L12 or 78M12 etc. For only 0.5A I'd probably use a [AO3400A](http://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AO3400A.pdf) because I happen to have a reel of them on hand, but the SOT-23 is pretty easy to fry if anything bad happens (like input floating) so a 10K-100K gate-source is a good idea.

Comment: Damn, these are SMD and my hand is also flickering so I was thinking of THT more. Yeah I can add it and I think I will, as my voltage regulator is getting very hot right now

Comment: You'll find that most modern logic level MOSFETs are SMT only. Worth acquiring the skill set to work with them.

Comment: Marek, the 20V spec on Vgs for the 16NF06FP is the absolute max voltage.  The recommended drive voltage to turn the FET fully ON is 10V.

Comment: Thanks @SpehroPefhany, BTW. If AO3400A has a max Vds(th) = 1.45 V it means that max output voltage will be at PWM equal 113? (1.45V*255)/3.3V, and all over will provide same output voltage?

Comment: You drive it on with the full 3.3V from the MCU. It will have less than 24 milliohm resistance typically (that's the typical with 2.5V drive and it will be less at 3.3V), so it will drop only about 12mV at 0.5A. 0V is off. Vgs(th) just gives you an idea of where it's almost off. You want to drive it fully on and fully off (or it will burn up).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I have bought IRL530N and IRL540N as these were the only logic mosfets a store had, but the problem is still occuring, Vmax on output is 17.17 V. I have also tried with TIP120 with base pullup resistor 1k to 12 V and a 1k base resistor and output is 22.5 V which is fine, but I can't control it with mcu, changing PWM does nothing.